# how to translate this rails "verify"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Since verify has been deprecated:

```
  verify :method => :get, :only => [ :logout, :index ],
         :redirect_to => { :action => :index }

  verify :method => :post, :only => [ :login ],
         :redirect_to => { :action => :index }
```

Archives say, use before filter, how to translate it into before filter?

Other archives says, if you use REST routes, verify or before_filter is not needed. What would be my routes be like then? Currently it is

```
Get ‘login’ => ‘login#login’
```

Comment: I think you didn't give us the controller. Also, you are just redirecting: logout, index, login all to "index" action?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show us which controller are you using those routes from. I suppose it's User, so the translation should be:

```
resources :users, only: [:index] do
    collection do
        # Should be delete, not get
        get  'logout', to: redirect('/index_or_whatever_you_want')
        post 'login',  to: redirect('/same_as_before')
    end
end
```

### Update after clarifying controller name

```
get  'logout' => 'login#index'
post 'login', => 'logout#index'
```

Notice that you are definitely missing the point in "RESTful routes" in this way. These lines should be put in `config/routes.rb` file

### Update after noticing the typo

Sorry I just noticed that I swapped the two actions, that's why the previous code resolved in an infinite loop, you should use this instead:

```
get  'logout' => 'login#index'
post 'login', => 'login#index'
```

Comment: hi! it's on LoginController

Comment: what does route that mean in english? :-)

Comment: It's a rails functionality... there isn't a direct translation, you can suppose it as hooking URLs to controller actions (controller methods), anyway if controller is logincontroller you can just change resources :users to resources :login, you will have the strange path "login/logout" by the way...

Comment: @user2585040: I updated the answer after you clarified the controller that should be used.

Comment: the logout is in ApplicationController    def logout
    redirect_to '/login'
  end

Comment: having added the above route, application now seems to be going on a infinite loop. browser does not show anything until it stops. the log repeatedly shows rendering...

Comment: What do you have in the `def login` method?

Comment: @user2585040: I don't think it's valid having an action inside ApplicationController, you should have `logout` on the same controller as `login`, anyway read for the fix. You should definitely read some tutorials anyway, you are doing everything in the weirdest way I've ever seen.

Comment: thank you fire-dragon-dol for guiding me thru this. still receiving bunch of errors. but it's of different context now. i'm trying to play with an old simple app. hoping to learn rails thru this app.